# Split pandas column on number with %

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a df with one of the columns that appears like:

```
**Share**
We are safe 25%
We are always safe 12.50% (India Aus, West)
We are ok (USA, EU)
We are not OK
What is this
Always wise 25.66%
```

I want to split this column such that the % values wherever applicable get split from the column into a new one.
So the output would be

```
Share                  Percent    LOCATION
We are safe            25%  
We are always safe     12.50%     India Aus, West
We are ok                         USA, EU
We are not OK
What is this
Always wise            25.66%
```

I thought the below would split it from right, but it is not working

```
df['Percent'] = df['Share'].str.rsplit(r' \d',1).str[0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract those values:

```
df[['Share','Percent']] = df['Share'].str.split(r'\s+(?=\d+(?:\.\d+)?%\s*$)',expand=True).fillna("")
```

Pandas test:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Share':['We are safe 25%','We are ok', 'We are always safe 12.50%']})
df[['Share','Percent']] = df['Share'].str.split(r'\s+(?=\d+(?:\.\d+)?%\s*$)',expand=True).fillna("")
>>> df
                Share Percent
0         We are safe     25%
1           We are ok        
2  We are always safe  12.50%
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sLhDHn/3). Details:

- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(?=\d+(?:\.\d+)?%\s*$)` - a positive lookahead matching a location that is immediately followed with:

  - `\d+` - one or more digits
  - `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional sequence of `.` and one or more digits
  - `%` - a `%` symbol
  - `\s*`  - 0 or more trailing (as `$` comes next) whitespaces and
  - `$` - end of string.

Comment: thanks a lot, but i dont want the %ages in the first column

Comment: i guess then it will be split
df['Share','Percent'] = df['Share'].str.split(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?%)\s*$',expand=True).fillna("")

Comment: regex..demo site is simply amazing..did not know this..Thanks a ton!!

Comment: @asimo When using `split`, you will get 3 columns, so it is not fine. Try another solution I edited the answer to.

Comment: I have made a slight change to the question. Essentially, now trying to split and/or on seeing a percent or a opening parenthesis